# how get pose(x,y,z) of links and plot in rqt?

Tags: ros, pose, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi. I want plot position (x y z) for camera and second link for [RRRBot robot](https://github.com/JoshMarino/gazebo_and_ros_control).

[NEngelhard](http://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) told me: "
you need to use a tf listener to get the pose and republish these values so that rqt_plot is able to plot them. "

but I do not know what to do. can any body write tf listener for [RRRBot robot](https://github.com/JoshMarino/gazebo_and_ros_control) ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255597/how-get--pose(x,y,z)-of-links-and-plot-in-rqt?/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2017-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a full example (just google "tf listener": [tf listener](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20(C%2B%2B))

Just replace the frames by the ones you need (Most probably something like 'world' and 'link3' for your robot) and publish the position.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-03-03**:
please check my answer